# Sci-fi/horror movie about a creature or monster loose in a facility in the middle of a desert

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched this movie long back, so I don't remember much. It might be a late '90s or early 2000s film. I remember only the following points:

1. The movie's opening titles have a shower scene of an actress.
2. Basic plot: A creature or monster is loose in a facility in the middle of a desert. The team has to eliminate it and survive.
3. At the end, while the surviving members leave in a helicopter with the monster's body lying in the desert, the monster's fingers move, indicating that it is still alive.

Please help me find this movie.

Comment: Mind ripper seems similar especially the ending , but does the movie have an opening shower scene, if so then that's the movie

Comment: This is why I love the internet!!! I never thought i would get this movie name with so little information!! Thanks a lot valorum, indeed the movie i'm searching for is mind ripper!!!

Comment: [Not a problem.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ) Enjoy your film :-)